# Phone keeps crashing and restarting after rooting

Tags: root-access, hardware

My phone (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge SM-G925F) keeps crashing, freezing and/or restarting after I rooted it. Previously I also updated the firmware but the problem only rose after rooting it. I have tried both wiping cache and factory reset. Should I reflash firmware/unroot or try to re-root via Odin. I also checked it with Root Checker and it says it is properly rooted. Thanks

Update: I reflashed firmware again after phone shut down by itself and went into a bootloop, phone stayed frozen on the recovery screen for a long time giving me a mini heart attack. **Could it be that Knox is making problems, the counter was tripped when I first rooted the phone.**

Comment: How did you root?

Comment: Via Odin using file from CF Auto Root. I used Odin 3.12 if that helps. I do not have custom recovery. Also I just tried flashing stock firmware but after successfully loading in download mode it is stuck at erasing in recovery mode

Comment: Did you first rooted phone and than installed some of updates or other way around?

Comment: I would definitely suggest reflashing the firmware.

Comment: I did reflash but now the phone keeps restarting and crashing on unrooted stock Nougat firmware too

Comment: @Једноруки Крстивоје Yes I rooted the phone and then upgraded to the Android Nougat update for my phone

Comment: Well you shouldn't do that because that never ends well, when you root your phone you must give up ona ota updates. Flash stock firmware and you are good to go.

Comment: @Једноруки Крстивоје Phone is working well so far but I still want to root. Any advice

Comment: Just root it the way you did it before but don't accept OTA updates of system anymore. Wait did your phone worked fine when  you rooted it previously (until you updated to nougat)?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје КрстивојеRooting or stock firmware, the phone keeps freezing and crashing nonetheless. It crashed on stock Marshmallow as well as rooted.